# Logs (Log4j) not showing up when system reboots while running Jar file as a service

Tags: java, linux, unix, logging, jar

I have cerated a SpringBoot application using maven and deployed the code in AWS Linux. I am running Jar file (Created from mvn clean package) as a service. However Logs are not generating when the system reboots.If I just terminate the ssh session and open the new SSH terminal, I am able to see the logs getting generated.However the issue is only while the system reboots as the application runs in the background but logger doesn't work though.  I have written the shell script where I set the environmental variables every time I start the service/ or system reboots. So every time I start the service manually/System reboot environmental variables will be set.It works when I manually run the service (sudo service myapp start) but environment variables are not set when the system reboots.

My project structure
I have placed startup script and stop scripts in my scripts folder

start.sh:
    cd /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver
    sudo -E java -jar target/osu-soap-server-0.1.0.jar &

Stop.sh:
   sudo fuser 8090/tcp -k || true

I have created myapp in /etc/init.d

myapp:

```html
source /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver/scripts/osuscript.sh
case $1 in
    start)
        /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver/scripts/start.sh
    ;;
    stop)
        /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver/scripts/stop.sh
    ;;
    restart)
         /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver/scripts/start.sh
        /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/webserver/osuserver/scripts/stop.sh
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Also to start the service everytime the system reboot, I am placing the a command to start a service in /etc/rc.local

**sudo service myapp start**

So whenever I reboot the system, I can see the application running in the background as most of the API which is not dependent on environmental variables works. The issue is with Logs and environment variables. After system reboots, application doesn't write any log to the file and environment variables are null (may be my script file where I set env variable is not being executed).However application run in the background.

So I want to know whether I need to change  the way I am running the jar file as a service? or any other options?

Comment: which system 'user' own logs directory ? is it same "who" run the process from boot  ?

Comment: Yes log directory belongs to the same user who owns the logs directory and  it's the same user who run the process from the boot.